# No overload for method 'Initialize' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm very new to C# and am trying to follow this tutorial on implementing CefSharp: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990346/Using-HTML-as-UI-Elements-in-a-WinForms-Applicatio#_articleTop

However, when I try to use the code he provides in the first snippet, i get;

Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'Initialize' takes 0 arguments

I looked at other instances of this error, but it involved having a wrong amount of arguements, and I dont believe there should be an arguement for Initialize.

Any help would be appreciated (most likely a very simple error),
Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace multidiscordmanager {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Initialize();
            ChromiumWebBrowser myBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.maps.google.com");
            this.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to call the constructor that takes CefSettings?  If you right click on Cef and select “go to definition”, you should be able to see the meta-data for the Cef class.  The meta-data will show you all of the overloads for the Initialize method. Make sure there is a parameter-less initialize method in the meta data. Based on their documentation, there certainly should be, but maybe this will point you towards the root cause of your problem.

Comment: I have these meta-data definitions for Initialize: public static bool Initialize(AbstractCefSettings cefSettings, bool performDependencyCheck, IBrowserProcessHandler browserProcessHandler); and public static bool Initialize(AbstractCefSettings cefSettings);

Comment: If the parameterless Initialize method isn’t showing in the meta data, the compiler has no idea that it exists. You need to figure out why you’re only seeing one of the three overloads. Maybe you have a dependency issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The tutorial you are referencing is old and out of date.

In version 67.0.0 Cef.Initialize() was removed and that line of code can safely be removed. You only need to call Cef.Initlalize(settings) if you are providing custom settings. To initialize with the defaults the first instance of ChromiumWebBrowser will do that for you.

See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown for background information.

Comment: Cef.Initialize was removed in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/366d3a898c519a8f8523fbf4868fffe616dd0b73

Answer (score -1):

When working in WinForms we most often see things like `InitializeComponent` which, indeed, takes no parameters.

What you're invoking is `Cef.Initialize` which [according to the CEFSharp documentation](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_Initialize_1.htm) takes a parameter of `CefSettings settings`

**Edit:** I'm blind, apparently, and there *is* an overload in the docs that is parameterless but it's clearly not available to your class.

If you're not seeing the overload that takes no parameters then something else is mismatched like the library version or the framework.

Comment: According to the CEFSharp documentation there is also an overload that takes no arguments. https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_Initialize.htm

Comment: Well.  It seems I'm nearly blind.  Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: By using InitializeComponent() I no longer get an error but no page loads

Comment: That's the winforms `InitializeComponent` and likely isn't initializing `Cef` at all.  This behavior sure looks like the WPF implementation according to Cef's documentation.

Comment: The tutorial is weirdly structured, they begin by refereing to a WPF starter tutorial but then use forms :/

Comment: Is there a better beginner tutorial you could recommend? I dont mind if its WPF or Form based as long its consistant

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1058700/Embedding-Chrome-in-your-Csharp-App-using-CefSharp you can try this one.  It looks almost the same, but doesn’t have the WPF links at the beginning. Did you follow the steps in the WPF links from the first tutorial?

Comment: The API doc is version specific, the version you are linking to is version 51, and is only valid for version 51. The list of version docs is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/